# Ключ авторизации перед началом работы скрипта Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, аутентификация, key

есть код Python, открытый, хочу сделать для него ключ авторизации который будет привязан на сервере, например сделать 10 ключей и их можно активировать лишь 1 раз чтобы ключ привязался к ПК и сохранялся в licencekey.txt блокноте и после брал ключ авторизации из этого блокнота и выполнял код Python без повторного вода ключа.

Я знаю что нужно поставить сервер и туда добавить базу данных ключей, но как это сделать, и какой код нужен для того чтобы это работало в Python скрипте без проблем? Заранее благодарю за ответы

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: licencekey должен быть привязан к ОС или к железу?

Comment: вроде простая задача интересная и простая, но так много писать)

Comment: @eri, с языка снял )))

Comment: На сервере создаете базу данных с таблице, с ключами, предусмотрите там поля id, key, is_used. При первом запуске программы проверяете наличие и корректность licence.txt, если его нет или он сломан берете ключ из БД и записываете в файл, параллельно на сервере (а не в скрипте) необходимо отследить это, чтобы поставить галочку is_used или вообще удалить строку. Если при этом необходимо этот ключ намертво привязать к ПК, то это отдельный разговор, надо сделать аппаратный слепок системы и записать его в БД (для этого там отдельное поле должно быть аля system_hash). Простой сервер на питоне- flask

Comment: @eri , к железу

Comment: для привязки можно такое применить `open('/sys/block/sda/device/wwid','rb').read().split()[-1]`